# What is the fastest way to compare two dictionaries?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to workout the fastest way to match two dictionaries in Actionscript-3. This is what I've got so far.

```
function compareDictionaries(p0:Dictionary, p1:Dictionary):Boolean 
{
    if(p0 == p1) {
        return true;
    } else {

        const matched:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        for(var k0:Object in p0) {
            matched[k0] = k0;
            if(p0[k0] != p1[k0]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for(var k1:Object in p1) {
            if(matched[k1]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                if(p1[k1] != p0[k1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Obviously it's not ideal to create a new dictionary with the key for the item, but I really don't want to retest the matched item (not that I know if this is any slower or not!). This of course would be circumvented by having a length on the dictionary class, which would make the second for loop redundant.

Any better ideas over this?

**EDIT**

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2049496) of the benchmark to show the results for a successful match (use the release player)

(results output in (ms))
true
43
true
497
true
22
true
16

**EDIT 2**
I created another [gist](https://gist.github.com/2049529) showing a miss-hit of equality.

(results output in (ms))
false
1
false
472
false
0
false
0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this should work - no new arrays/dictionaries etc:

```
public function compareDictionaries( d1:Dictionary, d2:Dictionary ):Boolean
{
    // quick check for the same object
    if( d1 == d2 )
        return true;

    // check for null
    if( d1 == null || d2 == null )
        return false;

    // go through the keys in d1 and check if they're in d2 - also keep a count
    var count:int = 0;
    for( var key:* in d1 )
    {
        // check if the key exists
        if( !( key in d2 ) )
            return false;

        // check that the values are the same
        if( d1[key] != d2[key] )
            return false;

        count++;
    }

    // now just make sure d2 has the same number of keys
    var count2:int = 0;
    for( key in d2 )
        count2++;

    // return if they're the same size
    return ( count == count2 );
}
```

Technically you could just make a direct comparison with the values (as in don't check for the existence of the key in d2) as if you search for a key that's not there, it should resolve to `null` (or `undefined`, I'm not 100% sure), but I left it in there in the case where a value in `d1` is null and it doesn't exist in `d2`

Comment: You can't just use the keys from d1, because there might be more keys in d2, and then they still wouldn't be equal. Checking the number of keys is a way to do it, but I'd do it *before* comparing values.  Also, comparing simple equality would not be enough: as I've said, dictionary keys are based on identity, and that makes using `===` a necessity. That's why I chose to compare keys separately.  And finally, how expensive is `if (!key in ...)` for comparison?  It would have to iterate over all the keys for every key checked, wouldn't it?

Comment: if all the keys in `d1` are found in `d2` and the number of keys are the same, then it's safe to say that the keys match. I don't compare the lengths beforehand as that would necessitate 3 loops (2 for each length, then another to checks the keys/values) and I try to early out as quick as possible

Comment: The `if in...` check should be relatively quick - it's the same time to recover any object from a dictionary - I don't think it does an iteration over all the keys. It's the same as doing `if( d2[key] == undefined )`

Comment: Ok, I'll give you that, but to be sure the compiler knows that, I'd probably do the undefined check instead.

Comment: you're right on the strict equality check, but only on the dictionary values as you've the possibility of automatic data conversion

Comment: It's the dictionary *keys* that must be checked for strict equality.

Comment: ah, you're right - just tested it with primitive keys: `d1[2] = true; d2["2"] = true; // both pass the key check` - only object keys though and you're golden :D

Comment: It's worse: using both 2 and "2" when *writing* a value to the dictionary would cause it to be overwritten - just like it would in an Object.

Comment: I didn't know that, that is something very interesting and concerning!

Comment: @stickupkid - it all depends on your specific code, but it's not something I'd lose sleep over - just choose the best container for your code depending on what you want to use as a key. Objects -> `Dictionary`, Strings -> `Object`, int/uints -> `Array/Vector` etc etc

Comment: I agree with that and that's not the issue, finding things like that are annoying more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

Start by comparing strict equality. Then, test equality of the keys in both dictionaries:

- Iterate over the properties and return all keys in arrays
- Test for equal array length
- Sort the arrays
- Iterate once more for comparison

Only if all of those tests are passed, compare the actual values:

```
public function areEqualDictionaries( dict1:Dictionary, dict2:Dictionary ):Boolean {
    if(dict1 === dict2) return true;

    var keys:Array = equalKeysArrayOrNull( dict1, dict2 ); 
    if(keys) 
        return haveEqualValues( keys, dict1, dict2 );
    else
        return false;
}

private function equalKeysArrayOrNull( dict1:Dictionary, dict2:Dictionary ):Array {
    var keys1:Array = enumerateKeys( dict1 ).sort();
    var keys2:Array = enumerateKeys( dict2 ).sort();
    if( keys1.length != keys2.length ) return null;

    var i:int = -1;
    while(++i < keys1.length) 
        if(keys1[i] !== keys2[i]) return null;

    return keys1;
}

private function haveEqualValues ( keys:Array, dict1 : Dictionary, dict2:Dictionary) :Boolean {
    for each (var key:* in keys) 
        if (dict1[key] != dict2[key]) return false;
    return true;
}

private function enumerateKeys( dict:Dictionary ):Array {
    var keys:Array = [];
    for(var key:* in dict) 
        keys.push( key );
    return keys;
}
```

Note that dictionaries use identity (strict equality) for matching keys, which makes it necessary to use `!==` for comparing them. I suppose it's okay to use `!=` for comparing the values, though.

## EDIT: Comparison of for vs. for each

Here's my own benchmark `for` vs. `for each`:

```
var dict : Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var keys : Array = [];
for (var i : int = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    var n : Object = { index:i };
    dict[n] = n;
    keys.push (n);
}

trace ("benchmark:");

trace ("----------");
var start : int = getTimer();

for each (var key:* in keys) {
    var m:* = dict[key];
}
var elapsed : int = getTimer() - start;
trace ("for each:" + elapsed);

trace ("----------");
start = getTimer();

for (var j:int = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    var o:* = dict[keys[j]];
}
elapsed = getTimer() - start;
trace ("for:" + elapsed);
```

returns on my machine:

```
for each:213
----------
for:274
```

Comment: considering `sort()` can be a relatively expensive operation (and assigns memory), you should check the lengths match before calling it. also, a simple `for` loop is faster than a `for each`

Comment: `sort()`is a native function and pretty fast.  I kept it inline, because it just reads better ;)  But you're right - to be all correct it should be called after the length comparison.

Comment: I would also like to know where you got the info on `for each`- from what I have seen in decompiled sources, all array loops are converted to `while (++i < arr. length)` loops in byte code.

Comment: `for each` vs `for` was from my own tests, but this link has a good enough comparison as any: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/358 (though tbh, for the most common size arrays it won't make a huge difference)

Comment: That just goes to teach you about benchmarks... The test uses int values for dictionary keys.  But using simple values on a dictionary is the same as using `Object` - it ignores all the inner functionality of dictionary and simply adds a dynamic value.  Sure, iterating over an array of ints is faster than a for each on an array of ints.  How about a comparison using mixed keys, and actual objects nonetheless?  I've edited my answer to show my own benchmark results.

Comment: Can you run that and tell me what you're getting: http://wonderfl.net/c/4jt9 - for me `for` is quicker than `for each` - tho on about 1m iters :D

Comment: I get about the same result as you: for each on an array is slightly slower. It seems, though, that the combination of for each (array) and using the values to access a dictionary is a lot faster. Go figure. ;)

Comment: Also note that you're using the debug player so the results are not accurate representation of what users will see. You should make sure you turn -debug=false and test in the release player.